# Is the dispatch of a Haskell TypeClass dynamic?

Tags: haskell, dynamic, static, typeclass, dispatch

Given the following Haskell code snapshot:

```
class Foo a where
   bar  :: a -> ...
   quux :: a -> ...
   ...
```

Where the value of a is determined at runtime - the class dispatches on this value.

I'm assuming that the compiler can statically check the types at compile-time, and ensure that no invalid types can dispatch on it.

Now if we compare this to a dynamic dispatch in Java:

```
interface Flippable {
  Flippable flip();
}

class Left implements Flippable {
  Right flip();
}

class Right implements Flippable {
  Left flip();
}

class Demo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Flippable flippable = new Right();
    System.out.println(flippable.flip);
  }
}
```

**Assumptions:**

- Haskell can dispatch on return type as well as multiple arguments making dispatch different to other languages.

My question is: **Is the dispatch of a Haskell TypeClass dynamic?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "dynamic" dispatch. There aren't subtyping in haskell, so your Java example is hard to translate.

In situation when you have type class, say `Show` and want to put different elements into the list, you can use existential quantification:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Showable = forall a. Show a => Showable a

instance Show Showable where
  show (Showable x) = show x

test :: main ()
test = let list = [Showable True, Showable "string"]
       in print list

-- >>> test
-- [True,"string"]
```

Here you can say that dispatch happens "dynamically". It happens in the same way as in C++ or Java. The `Show` dictionary is carried with an object, like a *vtable* in C++ (or class definition ptr in Java, dunno how it's called).

Yet, as **@MathematicalOrchid** explained, this is an anti-pattern.

---

Yet if you want to flip from `Left` to `Right` and back, you can state that in type class definition.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Flippable a b | a -> b where
  flip' :: Flippable b a => a -> b

newtype INL = INL Int deriving Show
newtype INR = INR Int deriving Show

instance Flippable INL INR where
  flip' (INL x) = INR x

instance Flippable INR INL where
  flip' (INR x) = INL x

-- >>> flip' $ INL 1
-- INR 1
-- >>> flip' $ flip' $ INL 1
-- INL 1
```

In this case `flip'` calls are resolved already at compile-time.

---

You could have have `class Flip a where flip' :: a -> Flippable` using existential quantification too. Then consecutive calls will be dispatched dynamically. As always, it depends on your needs.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

class Flip a where
  flip' :: a -> Flippable

-- Show is only for repl purposes
data Flippable = forall a. (Flip a, Show a) => Flippable a

deriving instance Show Flippable

instance Flip Flippable where
  flip' (Flippable x) = flip' x

newtype INL = INL Int deriving Show
newtype INR = INR Int deriving Show

instance Flip INL where
  flip' (INL x) = Flippable (INR x)

instance Flip INR where
  flip' (INR x) = Flippable (INL x)

-- >>> flip' $ flip' $ flip' $ INL 1
-- Flippable (INR 1)
```

---

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks that's awesome - could you clarify re Flipping from Left to Right - could the state of Flippable be determined at runtime?

Comment: You can add a method to `Flippable` interface to determine whether it's left or right. But this sounds already that, you are searching for ADT: `Either a a` or `(Bool, a)` (boolean tells the state).

Answer (score 7):

If your code is Haskell 2010, with no language extensions turned on, Haskell actually doesn't support run-time polymorphism *at all!*

That's quite surprising. Haskell feels like a very polymorphic language. But in fact, all the types can in principle be decided purely at compile-time. (GHC chooses not to, but that's an implementation detail.)

This is exactly the same situation as C++ templates. When you write something like `std::vector<int>`, the compiler knows, at compile-time, all the times involved. The really surprising thing is just how rarely you actually *need* true run-time polymorphism!

Now, there are scenarios where you want to run different code based on run-time circumstances. But in Haskell, you can do that just by passing a function as an argument; you don't need to create a "class" (in the OOP sense) merely to achieve this.

Now, if you turn on some language extensions (most conspicuously `ExistentialQuantification`) then you get true, *run-time* polymorphism.

Note that the main reason people seem to do this is so you can do

```
class Foo f where
  bar :: f -> Int
  baz :: f -> Bool

data AnyFoo = forall f. Foo => AnyFoo f

my_list :: [AnyFoo]
...
```

This is widely considered a Haskell anti-pattern. In particular, if you upcast stuff in Java to put it into a list, you then later *downcast* it again. But the code above offers no possibility to ever downcast. You also can't use run-time reflection (since Haskell doesn't have that either). So really, if you have a list of `AnyFoo`, the *only* thing you can do with it is call `foo` or `bar` on it. So... why not just store the result of `foo` and `bar`?

```
data AnyFoo = AnyFoo {foo :: Int, bar :: Bool}
```

It lets you do exactly the same stuff, but doesn't require any non-standard extensions. In fact, in some ways, it's actually a bit more flexible. You now don't even *need* a `Foo` class, you don't *need* to define a new type for every sort of `Foo` you might have, just a function that constructs the `AnyFoo` data structure for it.

Comment: doesn't `Typeable` gives possibility to "downcast" (not saying it's a good idea though).

Comment: @phadej Quite right. The pattern I showed above does _not_ allow downcasting. But `Typeable` and `Dynamic` exist precisely to allow downcasting.

Comment: It's not true that Haskell 2010 doesn't require runtime polymorphism.  Polymorphic recursion is runtime polymorphism, and part of the Haskell 2010 standard.  `f :: Show a => a -> Int -> String ;  f x 0 = show x ; f x n = f (x,x) (n - 1)`, for instance.

Comment: @Carl That's interesting. This is the first example of polymorphic recursion I've seen that doesn't actually admit a static resolution. It still seems a bit contrived though; I can't imaging much real-world code does this...

Comment: Not much, but occasionally it happens. Some of the algorithms working over `Data.Sequence.Seq` involve polymorphic recursion, due to the definition of the structure.

Comment: "if you have a list of AnyFoo, the only thing you can do with it is call foo or bar on it. So... why not just store the result of foo and bar?" --> Because foo and bar have side effects! In Java UI, it is very common to put objects into List<Drawable> and repeatedly take those objects out and ask them to .draw(), never downcasting them again.

Comment: In Haskell, expressions cannot cause side effects. That's why MathematicalOrchid said specifically that it's a Haskell anti-pattern.