# Generically finding out whether the type of a value belongs to a type class or not

Tags: haskell, reflection, typeclass

I want to write the `isShowable` function as part of this code.

```
data MaybeShowable = forall a . Show a => Showable a | Opaque
f :: (Data d) => d -> String
f x = case isShowable x of
        Showable s -> show s
        Opaque -> "<<OPAQUE>>"
isShowable :: (Data d) => d -> MaybeShowable
isShowable = ???
```

Is this possible by using the `Data` instance? If not, what is the best way to do it?

Note: If there's no other option, I'm willing to settle for this a version that works only for type class instances visible through the imports to the module in which `isShowable` is defined.

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible to extract the typeclass instances for a particular value at runtime.  It's not part of the `Data.Typeable` or `Data.Data` APIs that I could find.

Comment: If this were possible separate compilation would be quite hard to perform correctly. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: If I would be willing to settle for "typeclass instances visible through the imports to the module in which `isShowable` is defined", will it change your answer?  @bheklilr @chi

Comment: In that case there might be some type class hack which could achieve that, exploiting `IncoherentInstances` or related extensions. I am not so fluent in that area to give a definite answer, though.

Comment: @chi - I just wish to note that if isShowable is always forcibly inlined using Template Haskell (like a C macro), then it becomes much more usable under the restriction I've mentioned. That is why I am still interested in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what is your real intention is, but it looks like you'd like to embed Java idiom into Haskell.

As mentioned [in other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28170590/1308058) what you are doing is going to turn into anti-pattern.

You have added a clarification:

> If I would be willing to settle for "typeclass instances visible through the imports to the module in which `isShowable` is defined".

Why wouldn't you wrap your type in:

```
data MaybeShowable a where
  Showable :: forall b. Show b => b -> MaybeShowable b
  Opaque   :: forall b.           b -> MaybeShowable b

instance Show (MaybeShowable a) where
  show (Showable x) = show x
  show (Opaque x)   = "<<OPAQUE>>"
```

And have your functions operate on `MaybeShowable a`, instead of plain `a`.

Yet this is ugly still. Isn't it be easier to operate directly on `Show a => a`, or `a`.

Other way is to capture `Show a` dictionary early enough, i.e. have data type:

```
data MaybeShowable a = Showable a String -- Or even Showable a (a -> String)
                     | Opaque a

instance Show (MaybeShowable a) where
  show (Showable x s) = s
  show (Opaque x)     = "<<OPAQUE>>"

wrapShow :: Show a => a -> MaybeShowable a
wrapShow x = Showable x (show x) -- Showable x show

wrapOpaque :: a -> MaybeShowable a
wrapOpaque = Opaque
```

The variation of this approach is used in e.g. [QuickCheck's `forAll`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.4.0.1/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#forAll). That part is Haskell98. There the `show x` is closed over into closure, which maybe executed or not. Lazyness is the key point here!

Comment: You mean `wrapShow x = Showable x (show x)` , right?

Answer (score 2):

You can ask using template haskell which instances are available:

```
    module IsInstance where

    import Language.Haskell.TH; import Data.Typeable
    import Data.Generics; import Data.Monoid

    -- $(isInst ''Show) :: Typeable a => a -> Bool
    isInst :: Name -> ExpQ
    isInst className = do
        ClassI _ insts <- reify className
        ClassI _ typeableInsts <- reify ''Typeable
        let typeOfs = [ [| typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy $(return ty)) |]
                            | InstanceD _ (AppT _ ty) _ <- insts,
                              hasNoVarT ty,
                              or [ ty_ == ty | InstanceD _ (AppT _ ty_) _ <- typeableInsts ] ]
        [| \ val -> typeOf val `elem` $(listE typeOfs) |]

    hasNoVarT xs = getAll $ everything
        (<>)
        (mkQ mempty (\ x -> case x of
                      VarT {} -> All False
                      _ -> mempty))
        xs
```

`$(isInst ''Show) (1 :: Int)` is true, but unfortunately 
`$(isInst ''Show) (1 :: Rational)` is false, since here using `==` doesn't say that an instance for `Show (Ratio a)` can be used with `type Rational = Ratio Integer`. So a complete solution is going to have to know how instances are selected.

Comment: Can this function be used inside `f` from my original question? I get the impression that it only works for monomorphic input types.

Comment: Well `$(isInst ''Show) :: Typeable a => a -> Bool`, so technically yes it's polymorphic. But if you get a True, that doesn't let you call show, so it's kind of inadequate. We can generate a class with a method that figures out which GADT constructor to apply to a type (a manual part of @phadej 's solution). hat's done here: https://gist.github.com/aavogt/3d9d2b468fb51ec5d3ca